# AngularJs - update another page when data on this page changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 pages, controlled by 2 different controllers in the same ng-app.

Let's say they are:

```
app.com/budget/ - BudgetController
app.com/expense/ - ExpenseController
```

The budget page is for the user to edit budget values which will trip into the expense page data. Also on the expense page, there will be some more calculations which will save data into the database.

Normally the user changes the Budget data in the Budget page, then refresh/visit the Expense page for that page to save some new data into the DB.

Now I want this process to happen automatically when changing data in 1 page/controller will trigger the other page/controller to update. I was thinking of using ShareServices but those 2 controllers don't have much in common, apart from some queries to the same part of the DB.

Is there any better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a serviceProvider to help you encapsulate data shared by multiple controllers.

so in the budget page, you would something like

var myData = dataProvider.getData();
do your data manipulation.
before switching controller: dataProvider.saveData(myData)

in the expense controller,
var myData = dataProvider.getData();

and that's the single page application approach.

if you're using multiple page approach, then your dataProvider needs to talk to your saver to get and save the data.

I understand the pages don't have much in common, but the data that they need is common; so a shared service to get data works best.  In the long run the code in the shared services are reusable and will help out alot with maintaince.